# How to retract "always allow" safari permission for opening app?

Tags: safari, url

When opening a Zoom link in Safari, I'm typically prompted to allow Safari to open the Zoom app. Recently, with Safari 17, there's now an option to "Always Allow" Safari to open Zoom to handle links of this type, which I clicked.

However, I would now like to rescind that "Always Allow" permission and go back to having Safari ask me every time.

The reason is that I need to frequently switch Zoom accounts between two different SSO-enabled logins, and as soon as I try to switch accounts, Zoom opens Safari, which quickly logs me in to the account I'm trying to log *out* of, and then Safari re-launches Zoom with me logged back into the account I'm trying to leave. This makes it very difficult for me to switch accounts.

I've tried uninstalling/reinstalling Zoom, I've manually edited `com.apple.LaunchServices.plist` in Xcode to remove any entries associated with Zoom, but neither step has fixed the issue. If I change my default browser to Firefox, then I am once again prompted. I suspect that Safari is using some OS-wide settings whereas Firefox probably maintains its own link of what to do with various URI's.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot more experimentation, I was able to resolve this.

As far as I can tell, the relevant setting is not exposed to the user via any Safari configuration menus. However, the relevant setting is stored in `~/Library/Safari/PerSitePreferences.db`, which is an `sqlite` file. After dumping the database and poking around, I found the relevant entry and was able to remove it with the following SQL statement:

`DELETE FROM preference_values WHERE preference_value='zoommtg';`

After quitting and re-opening Safari, it once again asks me for permission to launch zoom, as I had desired.